# Yandex Maps - кластеры и фильтр. Как реализовать функцию кластеризации на Yandex карте?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, фильтры, кластеризация

Подскажите, как реализовать функцию кластеризации на Yandex карте?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Карта техники ROPA на территории РФ.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="geoobjects_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="clusterer_create.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        body, html {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 14pt;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #map {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 80%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div style="padding: 5px;">
        <div>
            Техника<br />
            <input type='checkbox' id='red' checked=true>Картофелеуборочная техника</input><br>
            <input type='checkbox' id='gray' checked=true>Погрузчики свеклы</input><br>
            <input type='checkbox' id='black' checked=true>Свеклоуборочный комбайн (черные)</input><br>
            <input type='checkbox' id='yellow' checked=true>Свеклоуборочный комбайн (желтые)</input>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Код Javascript

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [53.00, 59.45],
            zoom: 5
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 64,
            // Макет метки кластера pieChart.
            clusterIconLayout: "default#pieChart"
        });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    // Функция, которая по состоянию чекбоксов в меню
    // показывает или скрывает геообъекты из выборки.
    function checkState () {
        var shownObjects,
            byColor = new ymaps.GeoQueryResult();
            /*byShape = new ymaps.GeoQueryResult();*/

        // Отберем объекты по цвету. 
        if ($('#red').prop('checked')) {
            // Будем искать по двум параметрам:
            // - для точечных объектов по полю preset;
            // - для контурных объектов по цвету заливки.
            byColor = geoObjects.search('options.fillColor = "#cc3300"')
                .add(geoObjects.search('options.preset = "islands#redIcon"'));
        }
        if ($('#gray').prop('checked')) {
            byColor = geoObjects.search('options.fillColor = "#cccccc"')
                .add(geoObjects.search('options.preset = "islands#grayIcon"'))
                // После того, как мы нашли все зеленые объекты, добавим к ним
                // объекты, найденные на предыдущей итерации.
                .add(byColor);
        }
        if ($('#black').prop('checked')) {
            byColor = geoObjects.search('options.fillColor = "#000000"')
                .add(geoObjects.search('options.preset = "islands#blackIcon"'))
                .add(byColor);
        }
        if ($('#yellow').prop('checked')) {
            byColor = geoObjects.search('options.fillColor = "#ffd300"')
                .add(geoObjects.search('options.preset = "islands#yellowIcon"'))
                .add(byColor);
        }
        // Отберем объекты по форме.
        if ($('#point').prop('checked')) {
            byShape = geoObjects.search('geometry.type = "Point"');
        }
        if ($('#polygon').prop('checked')) {
            byShape = geoObjects.search('geometry.type = "Polygon"').add(byColor);
        }
        if ($('#circle').prop('checked')) {
            byShape = geoObjects.search('geometry.type = "Circle"').add(byColor);
        }

        // Мы отобрали объекты по цвету и по форме. Покажем на карте объекты,
        // которые совмещают нужные признаки.
        shownObjects = byColor.addToMap(myMap);
        // Объекты, которые не попали в выборку, нужно убрать с карты.
        geoObjects.remove(shownObjects).removeFromMap(myMap);
    }

    $('#red').click(checkState);
    $('#gray').click(checkState);
    $('#black').click(checkState);
    $('#yellow').click(checkState);
    $('#point').click(checkState);
    $('#polygon').click(checkState);
    $('#circle').click(checkState);

    // Создадим объекты из их JSON-описания и добавим их на карту.
    window.geoObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(
      {type: "FeatureCollection", 
       features: [
          {type: 'Feature', geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [55.34954, 37.721587]}, 
          "properties": {"balloonContent": "M", "hintContent": "M"}, 
          options: {preset: 'islands#grayIcon'}},
          {type: 'Feature', geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [55.24954, 37.4]},
         "properties": {"balloonContent": "P", "hintContent": "P"},
                options: {preset: 'islands#blackIcon'}},
          {type: 'Feature', geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [55.14954, 37.61587]},
              "properties": {"balloonContent": "K", "hintContent": "K"},
                options: {preset: 'islands#redIcon'}},
          {type: 'Feature', geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [55.396969, 43.830201]},
            "properties": {"balloonContent": "K", "hintContent": "K"},
                options: {preset: 'islands#redIcon'}},
          {type: 'Feature', geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [52.885420, 35.956179]},
            "properties": {"balloonContent": "P", "hintContent": "P"},
                options: {preset: 'islands#blackIcon'}},
            {type: 'Feature', geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [53.081306, 39.605717]}, 
            "properties": {"balloonContent": "T", "hintContent": "T"},
                options: {preset: 'islands#yellowIcon'}},
          {type: 'Feature', geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [55.518258, 50.307525]},
            "properties": {"balloonContent": "K", "hintContent": "K"},
                options: {preset: 'islands#redIcon'}}
        ]
    }).addToMap(myMap);

  clusterer.add(geoObjects);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);

    myMap.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds(), {
        checkZoomRange: true
    });
}
```

---

Есть второй вариант: реализована кластеризация, пробую функцию фильтра. Никак не пойму в чем же дело?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Карта техники</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="geoobjects_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="clusterer_pie_chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="object_manager_filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            max-width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Код Javascript:

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 5
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
            // Макет метки кластера pieChart.
            clusterIconLayout: 'default#pieChart',
            // Радиус диаграммы в пикселях.
            clusterIconPieChartRadius: 25,
            // Радиус центральной части макета.
            clusterIconPieChartCoreRadius: 10,
            // Ширина линий-разделителей секторов и внешней обводки диаграммы.
            clusterIconPieChartStrokeWidth: 3,
            // Определяет наличие поля balloon.
            hasBalloon: true
        }),
        points = [
          [55.396969, 43.830201], [52.885420, 35.956179], [56.871868, 35.914011], [51.730361, 36.192647], [52.728047, 41.422920], [53.258703, 34.392345], [55.796289, 49.108795] 
        ],
        points2 = [
          [53.081306, 39.605717]
        ]
        geoObjects = [];
/**************************************************************/
    for (var i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
        geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark(points[i], {balloonContent: 'K'}, {
            iconColor: '#cc3300'
        });
    }

  for (var i = 0, len = points2.length; i < len; i++) {
        geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark(points2[i], {balloonContent: 'T'}, {
            iconColor: '#ffd300'
        });
    }

    clusterer.add(geoObjects);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);

    myMap.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds(), {
        checkZoomRange: true
    });
 /****************************************************/
// Создадим пункты выпадающего списка.
    var listBoxItems = ['K', 'M', 'P', 'T']
        .map(function(title) {
            return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: title
                },
                state: {
                    selected: true
                }
            })
        }),
        // Список 
        listBoxControl = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
            data: {
                content: 'Фильтр',
                title: 'Фильтр'
            },
            items: listBoxItems,
            state: {
                // Признак, развернут ли список.
                expanded: true,
                filters: listBoxItems.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
                    filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
                    return filters;
                }, {})
            }
        });
    myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl);

    // Добавим отслеживание изменения признака, выбран ли пункт списка.
    listBoxControl.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
        var listBoxItem = e.get('target');
        var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, listBoxControl.state.get('filters'));
        filters[listBoxItem.data.get('content')] = listBoxItem.isSelected();
        listBoxControl.state.set('filters', filters);
    });

    var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(listBoxControl.state);
    filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {
        // Применим фильтр.
        objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(filters));
    });

    function getFilterFunction(categories){
        return function(obj){
            var content = obj.properties.balloonContent;
            return categories[content]
        }
    }
  /***************************************************/
});
```

---

Весь код в html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Карта техники</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="geoobjects_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="clusterer_pie_chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="object_manager_filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            max-width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
            zoom: 5
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
            // Макет метки кластера pieChart.
            clusterIconLayout: 'default#pieChart',
            // Радиус диаграммы в пикселях.
            clusterIconPieChartRadius: 25,
            // Радиус центральной части макета.
            clusterIconPieChartCoreRadius: 10,
            // Ширина линий-разделителей секторов и внешней обводки диаграммы.
            clusterIconPieChartStrokeWidth: 3,
            // Определяет наличие поля balloon.
            hasBalloon: true
        }),
        points = [
          [55.396969, 43.830201], [52.885420, 35.956179], [56.871868, 35.914011], [51.730361, 36.192647], [52.728047, 41.422920], [53.258703, 34.392345], [55.796289, 49.108795] 
        ],
        points2 = [
          [53.081306, 39.605717]
        ]
        geoObjects = [];
/**************************************************************/
    for (var i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
        geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark(points[i], {balloonContent: 'K'}, {
            iconColor: '#cc3300'
        });
    }

  for (var i = 0, len = points2.length; i < len; i++) {
        geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark(points2[i], {balloonContent: 'T'}, {
            iconColor: '#ffd300'
        });
    }

    clusterer.add(geoObjects);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);

    myMap.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds(), {
        checkZoomRange: true
    });
 /****************************************************/
// Создадим пункты выпадающего списка.
    var listBoxItems = ['K', 'M', 'P', 'T']
        .map(function(title) {
            return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: title
                },
                state: {
                    selected: true
                }
            })
        }),
        // Список 
        listBoxControl = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
            data: {
                content: 'Фильтр',
                title: 'Фильтр'
            },
            items: listBoxItems,
            state: {
                // Признак, развернут ли список.
                expanded: true,
                filters: listBoxItems.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
                    filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
                    return filters;
                }, {})
            }
        });
    myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl);

    // Добавим отслеживание изменения признака, выбран ли пункт списка.
    listBoxControl.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
        var listBoxItem = e.get('target');
        var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, listBoxControl.state.get('filters'));
        filters[listBoxItem.data.get('content')] = listBoxItem.isSelected();
        listBoxControl.state.set('filters', filters);
    });

    var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(listBoxControl.state);
    filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {
        // Применим фильтр.
        objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(filters));
    });

    function getFilterFunction(categories){
        return function(obj){
            var content = obj.properties.balloonContent;
            return categories[content]
        }
    }
  /***************************************************/
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Соберите, пожалуйста, полный исполняемый пример, чтобы было удобно отлаживаться. Сейчас видно, что у вас подключаются скрипты, кода которых тут нет.
Также из вопроса непонятно, что именно не так - в чем трудность и ошибка.
Вот примеры по этим темам в песочнице Яндекса: [фильтрация объектов](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_filter?from=SO) и [круговые диаграммы PieChart](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_pie_chart?from=SO)

Comment: Дописала полный код карты. 
Диаграммы работают. Фильтры прописаны, но не действуют.
Подскажите, мне было бы проще через формат json. Но он не подключается. Я пробовала по примеру фильтрации объектов.

Comment: а можете дать ссылку на jsfiddle, например? просто по листингу кода ничего не отладишь(

Comment: https://codepen.io/katerina19/pen/pOPJmw - я пользуюсь codepen

Comment: При попытке выбрать какой-то элемент из listbox падает ошибка что objectManager не определен. У вас нет objectManager на карте.

Comment: у вас там куча ошибок в консоли - в частности не подключают скрипты, которые указаны в тегах <script>. В коде куча ошибок не про API- исправьте их, пожалуйста, чтобы локализовать проблему только до ObjectManager. Или можно попробовать начать с чистого листа - скопируйте пример из песочницы и постепенно обновляйте его до нужного вида.

Comment: Да, теперь и сама вижу. не смотрела до этого момента консоль.
Скажите, пожалуйста, если из песочницы по примеру "Фильтрации объектов", где требуется файл data.json, где его нужно разместить, чтобы он брал данные из файла?

Comment: Положить в любом месте где он будет доступен) Например в туже папку где расположен ваш код. Во время отладки можно содержимое файла добавить внутрь кода https://jsfiddle.net/mnyqLswk/

Comment: @se0ga, спасибо большое! Теперь я увидела в чем была загвоздка. Я в самом файле data.json объявляла var data. )))